# Trying to reset the ID in SharePoint List with workflow

Tags: list, error, id

Trying to reset the Id field in SP list.

Created a new list by saving the template and uploading it again using the app option.

The list gets created however when I run the workflow some fields do not populate and all are person or group type.

I tried creating the workflow again and linking it to the newly created list but it still gives Required info error (highlighted in yellow) or the field remains blank and the workflow does not work as it sends an email once all field details are available.

please help as trying to figure out the error since last week.

Comment: Please specific the Sharepoint version and what kind of workflow you are using. Also are you going to upload an image?

Comment: Have you saved the template "with content"? Have you created your new list in another site collection? Can you add any new item in newly created list using `new item` button on list view??

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2013 and the list was created without content.

Comment: Checked the forms in infopath for the missing info fields and did not find anything linked to the field. Assigned the field to another fields linked like name of created by and now the error is gone and the workflow is working fine.  When saving the lists do the fields linked to another fields disappear?